# Sample tool in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst not working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

In ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop I am trying to use the spatial analyst tool 'sample' to extract data from several layers.

I have double checked and the input location raster is in the same format and cell size as the input raster, however the tool will not run.

The couple of times I have got the tool to run it has not populated the table with data or the data has been incorrect.

I have not previously had a problem whilst doing something similar with other data sets on an other computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that they are in the same projection? The function should probably handle this, but in some cases I suppose it could cause problems.

Comment: Use ArcGIS 10.0 or 10.2, not 10.1.

Answer (score 3):

If your rasters are in Esri Grid format then there is a bug called NIM089383:

> The Sample tool fails to produce values in the output table with Esri
>   GRIDs that worked in the previous version.

It's [solved in 10.2.1](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/1021-IssuesAddressedList.pdf).

If you can't upgrade and if you use GRID rasters, try converting them to another format.